# Creating a list of groups of pairs under constraint

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create a list of groups of pairs given a list of pairs, e.g., `[(a1,b1), (a2,b2)...]` such that all tuples in each resulting group satisfies the constraint

`abs(ai - aj) < 2` and `abs(bi - bj) < 3`.

For instance, given:

`[(1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 15)]`

the result will be a list of 3 groups:

`[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 4), (7, 5)], [(8, 15)]]`. Similarly:

- `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4)]` -> `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 2)], [(9, 3), (10, 4)]]`
- `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 2), (7, 4), (8, 15)]` -> `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 2), (7, 4)], [(8, 15)]]`

Does anyone know of an efficient way to create the groups?

Comment: Does `ai` mean index 0 and `aj` index 1?

Comment: @pstatix `ai` and `aj` represent the first elements of different tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [(1,2),(2,3),(6,4),(7,5),(8,15)]
new_data = [d for c, d in [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda (x, y):(abs(x-y) < 2, abs(x-y) < 3))]]
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 4), (7, 5)], [(8, 15)]]
```

Since the above answer utilizes `lambda` tuple unpacking, it will not work for Python3. However, for a Python3 compatible solution, use the code below:

```
import itertools
s = [(1,2),(2,3),(6,4),(7,5),(8,15)]
new_data = [d for c, d in [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:(abs(x[0]-x[1]) < 2, abs(x[0]-x[1]) < 3))]]
```

Comment: Thanks. However I don't quite understand how the `key` function works here. Doesn't `lambda (x, y):(abs(x-y) < 2, abs(x-y) < 3))` mean subtracting the the first of the tuple by the second of the tuple? It's meant to subtract the first of two tuples instead.

Comment: @JohnMunroe apologies, typo in my last comment. In the tuple unpacking, `(x, y)` are understood to be `ai, aj` to later perform the necessary subtraction and comparison.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this quite works. For instance, if `s = [(1,2),(2,3),(6,2),(7,4),(8,15)]` it gives `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 2), (7, 4), (8, 15)]]` even when `(8,15)` should belong to a separate group (15 - 4 > 3).

Comment: @JohnMunroe I am confused. Should not the grouping `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 2), (7, 4), (8, 15)]]` be correct for `s = [(1,2),(2,3),(6,2),(7,4),(8,15)]`, since `abs(1-2)` and `abs(2-3)` is less than 2, while `abs(6-2)`, `abs(7-4)`, and `abs(8-15)` are all greater than three, thus should go in a different grouping? However, you also introduced `15 - 4`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh, I'm not trying to compare first and second within the same tuple. I'm trying to compare values across tuples. The constraint `abs(ai - aj) < 2` actually means the difference between the first of two tuples is <2. The first group `[(1,2),(2,3)]` is good because `abs(1 - 2) < 2` and `abs(2 - 3) < 3` are satisfied. The second `[(6,2),(7,4)]` is good because `abs(2 - 6) > 2` warrants a split and `abs(6 - 7) < 2` and `abs(2 - 4) < 3`. However, `(8, 15)` warrants a split because `abs(4 - 15) < 3` is not satisfied. Hopefully it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

Without using any external library with one loop only :

```
data=[(1,2),(2,3),(6,4),(7,5),(8,15)]


print([(lambda x:x if abs(x[0][0]-x[1][0])<2 and abs(x[0][1]-x[1][1]<3) else 0)(data[i:i+2]) if len(data[i:i+2])>1 else data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)])
```

output:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 4), (7, 5)], [(8, 15)]]
```

Something with itertool (but its check with each element so result is little different you can use if you want something like that )

```
import itertools
data=[(1,2),(2,3),(6,4),(7,5),(8,15)]



print(list(filter(lambda y:y!=0,[(lambda x:x if abs(x[0][0]-x[1][0])<2 and abs(x[0][1]-x[1][1]<3) else 0)(i) for i in itertools.combinations(data, r=2)])))
```

**Updated code:**

```
data=[(1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4)]


print(list(filter(lambda y:y!=0,[(lambda x:x if abs(x[0][0]-x[1][0])<2 and abs(x[0][1]-x[1][1]<3) else 0)(data[i:i+2]) if len(data[i:i+2])>1 else data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)])))
```

output:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(10, 4)]]
```

P.S : if this solution helps you, don't accept the answer , just use it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works as intended. For the input `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (6, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4)]` it returns `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], 0, [(10, 4)]]` though.

Comment: The updated output is missing `(6, 2)` and `(9, 3)` though.

Comment: @JohnMunroe   what do you think what is the output of this expression abs(6-9)<2   True or False ?

Comment: abs(6 - 9) < 2 is False, so `(6,2)` and `(9,3)` should be to two separate groups, i.e. `[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(6, 2)], [(9, 3), (10, 4)]]`

Comment: @JohnMunroe is this result ok ?
[[(1, 2), (2, 3)], (2, 3), (6, 2), (9, 3), [(9, 3), (10, 4)]]

Comment: No, because each tuple should only occur once like in the original. The method should only group the tuples according to the two constraints.